# Not able to work with properties in matlab class

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

The following MATLAB code does not work.  I guess it has something to do that in the function changer, MATLAB tries to equal the objects `A` and `B` and not just setting the values to the same. Any workaround for that?

```
classdef foo
    %FOO Summary of this class goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here

    properties
        A=5
        B=0
    end

    methods
        function changer(obj)
            obj.B=obj.A
        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the code is actually working fine, just not doing quite what you expect.

The way you've defined it, `foo` is a *value* class, so it has value semantics, rather than reference (or handle) semantics. When you execute `changer(myobj)`, MATLAB is creating a copy of myobj with the new value of B and returning it to you. The original `myobj` remains unchanged. When implementing a value class, you would typically add an output argument to `changer` in order to be able to further work with this new copy.

```
function obj = changer(obj)
```

If you set foo to be a *handle* class, by inheriting from `handle`:

```
classdef foo<handle
```

it will then have reference (or handle) semantics, where the original `myobj` is modified (you then no longer need the output argument from `changer`):

```
>> myobj = foo;
>> changer(myobj); % or alternatively myobj.changer
>> myobj.B
ans =
     5
```